# Using strong parameters with Devise multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, activeadmin

I am getting the message, **Unpermitted parameter: email**, when signing up a new user (authenticated with devise)

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-01-10 00:19:01 +0200
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"omU3TFsQ5lG3SIvD7qSBi07VZywtL2EKIbTVn2q/Qt2PecCZvX6rlSEEiNg9yRPYgkDBkUDLbA59gJyUmQQNhA==", "user"=>{"username"=>"x", "email"=>"x@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
Unpermitted parameter: email
   (0.3ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered users/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (4.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered shared/_search.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 253ms (Views: 137.6ms | ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)
```

I am using **activeadmin** gem for administartion (which uses devise for Admin_user), and I am using devise for **another model** (User). I have override the users registration controller as below:

```
 class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

 before_filter :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
 before_filter :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]

 ...

 protected

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  def configure_sign_up_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email ,:password, :password_confirmation) }
  end

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  def configure_account_update_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :current_password ,:password, :password_confirmation) }
  end
end
```

I do not know what I am missing!

Comment: long shot but, could you try this syntax instead?
`devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: %i[username email current_password password password_confirmation])`
on both methods. That's how I have it working for something similar